# 'No write' variable in Python

Tags: python, matlab

In MATLAB you have the ability to return tuples and assign to tuples of values the same as you do so in Python. In MATLAB, if a function returns a value you don't want to assign to anything, you assign it to the special variable `~`. For example, say a function `f()` returns a tuple `(1, 2)`, then:

```
~, b = f()
```

Assigns `2` to `b` and `1` to nothing.

Is there an equivalent to this in Python? I understand I could just do:

```
a, b = f()
```

and ignore the value of `a` but I'd prefer skipping the assignment to `a` altogether. Rewriting the function `f()` is not an option.

I apologize if my Python terminology is wrong.

Comment: Both solutions are good, I'll take some time to decide what I want. Thanks for the fast response :)

Comment: The assignment to a is pretty trivial. You're not really saving anything by working around just not using a.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A common idiom in Python is to use `_` for this purpose.

However it's not necessarily a good idea because this variable is also used in the interactive interpreter for the last result and assigning to it will stop this useful feature from working.

Also `_` is sometimes used for string translation, e.g. with [`gettext`](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html).

Comment: pylint won't complain about unused variables if you assign it to the name 'dummy'. it's another common choice.

Comment: this should be equivalent to the `ans` variable in MATLAB (which was a common thing as well before `~` was introduced in recent versions)

Comment: Please don't use `_` as a dummy variable name.  In addition to the problems mentioned by Mark Byers, people tend to mistake `for _ in a` as some kind of special syntax, while `for dummy in a` is completely clear.  And I don't agree it is a common idiom in Python.  It seems to be a common Python idiom on SO, but I don't know where it originates from.

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively you can always just return the part of the tuple, you are interested in:

```
b = f()[1]
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid indexing because I feel that it's less readable, but it's definitely a solution.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's not a great solution.

Comment: This is the solution I'd use too. I don't think it diminishes readability that much. It's fairly common and pythonic.

Comment: If you are really concerned about readability, and you really think that indexing isn't readable, just write a wrapper function for `f()` that returns only the value you are interested in.